# Xpath last element with certain class in Odoo

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to replace the last div element with the class 'test' in Odoo.

I tried several things such as:

```
 <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('test')][last()]">
 <xpath expr="//div[@class='test'][last()]">
 <xpath expr="//div[@class='test'][-1]">
 <xpath expr="(//div[@class='test'])[last()]">
```

But none of them seem to work. I don't know if this is even possible in Odoo v14. I researched the open source code, but sadly I didn't find anything that can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The first `XPath` is valid and should select the last div with `test` class.

According to the [XPath](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/views.html#inheritance-specs) documentation:

> There is no limit to the number of predicates in a step, and they need not be confined to the last step in an XPath. They can also be nested to any depth.

You can find an example in the [website](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/website/views/website_templates.xml#L117) module:

```
<xpath expr="//head/t[@t-js='false'][last()]" position="after">
    
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to specify the position parameter

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('test')][last()]" position="replace">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).